# testNG testcase execution in particular order along with ability to start from particular testcase

Tags: automated-tests, testng

How to make the testNG testcase execution in a particular order along with the ability to start the execution from a particular testcase.

For eg. If you run the below suite

```
@Test
public class Test1 {
@Test
public void test1() {
    System.out.println("test1");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethod = "test1")
public void test2() {
    System.out.println("test2");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethod = "test2")
public void test3() {
    System.out.println("test3");
}
}
```

The order in which the testcases will executed will always be test1, test2, test3. But say sometime I want to start the execution from test2 and NOT from test1 i.e. I want to run test2 followed by test3 and without running test1. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `IAnnotationTransformer` that would turn the `enabled` attribute of `@Test` to `false`. However, you would have to adjust the dependencies as well.

I think it's probably simpler to put this logic in your test method themselves (if a certain condition is true, just do nothing instead of running the test and its asserts).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be add your tests to groups and then control the behavior from outside using testng.xml by specifying `<group>` let me know if you need further help on this.

Answer (score 0):

The simple idea is to have setting priority to different test; keep in mind that the default value for priority = 0.

```
@Test(priority=1)
public void t1(){}

@Test
public void t0(){}

@Test(priority=2)
public void t2(){}

@Test(priority=3)
public void t3(){}
```

So the execution sequence will be t0 -> t1 -> t2 -> t3.
t0 executes first as its priority is set to 0 by-default.

Hope this helps.